# Why is a non-Facebook tag necessary?

Tags: support, tags, mini-site, facebook.stackoverflow

I want to ask a question about Facebook's JavaScript SDK so I used that tag but the site won't allow me to post my question because it says I must also have a tag that's not related to Facebook!  This makes no sense to me! My question is about Facebook and the JavaScript SDK.  Why would I include a tag that's about something else?

Comment: What, exactly, does the message say?

Comment: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8753085/in-facebook-login-how-do-you-see-the-permissions-that-the-user-granted ... tagged `facebook` `javascript`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about the Facebook mini-site for Stack Overflow, which hasn't existed for years.

Answer (score 13):

Because chances are, your question is probably *about* something else. In addition to Facebook. Something more specific to the subset of all possible Facebook programming questions. And a tag that describes that topic goes a long way toward helping folks find it, understand it, and - hopefully - answer it...

So you gotta ask yourself, "I know my question is about Facebook, but what *else* is it about?"

Perhaps you're using [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+javascript). Or [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+php).

Maybe you're manipulating a browser's [DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+dom). Or generating [HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+html). Or authenticating with [OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook+oauth).

Those are all tags that could help to better classify your question. There are many others. Use them!

Comment: I used the tag "facebook-javascript-sdk.  Exactly what "non-facebook" tag should I add to "better classify" my question?  Your comment may have made sense when there was only a "facebook" tag but now we have things like "facebook-javascript-sdk" which says it all.  The site asking for an additional non-facebook tag to make it clearer is just plain confusing.

Comment: @Steve: actually, that tag describes *one thing*. It implies a couple of others (Facebook, JavaScript), but that doesn't mean you can't be explicit about them. And in fact, you *should*. And there's a pretty good chance that, whatever you're trying to do with the SDK, there's a tag for *that* too... Use it.

Comment: I added the (redundant) "JavaScript" tag and that got my question posted and then I got a very good answer right away, so it all ended well for me.  It does seem, though, that you guys are addressing the slowest 1% of people who come to these forums, which tends to confuse and insult the rest.  I mean, really, you're assuming that even though I've tagged my question "Facebook-javascript-sdk" I probably won't be able to describe it well enough to be  understood so I need to find more tags to help me. Already I feel insulted, before anyone has even seen what I write. Just some honest feedback.

Comment: @Steve: tagging serves a different purpose than simply describing the question as you stand looking at the page its on. I mean, it serves *that* purpose too... But that's not its primary role. And... It's not just the slow 1% that get it wrong. *Most* folks get it wrong. That's the problem with a folksonomy - the folks. If we can get one or two decent tags out of the author, editors can usually step in and add more as-needed - and just about anyone can edit.

Comment: What would you say the "something else" is for this question: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/12900549/how-do-i-get-the-upper-text-in-a-facebook-open-graph-action-story ?