# Why do I need to add a non-Facebook tag to a question when I'm only editing it (and didn't ask it)?

Tags: feature-request

Note, I'm not talking about arguing whether a [non-Facebook tag is necessary to begin with](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118109/why-is-a-non-facebook-tag-necessary), and I understand that the [error message I'm being given and why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103807/tag-requirement-issue-when-editing-question-on-facebook-stackoverflow-mini-site).

As an editor of a question that someone else posted, when I go to try to make the question better by editing the title, changing grammar, etc., I'm forced to also give the question a new tag. What is the intent?

To reproduce: go to facebook.stackoverflow.com. Find a question that has only Facebook related tags on it (because it was asked via stackoverflow.com). Edit the question.

Expected: any reasonable edit allowed.
Observed: You must add a non-Facebook tag.
Workaround: Changing URL to stackoverflow.com allows edit through.

Comment: Just to be clear; do you mean the question did not have a non-facebook tag to start with? Or did you remove it (perhaps because it did not apply)?

Comment: @AndrewBarber clarified. did not have a fb tag to start with.

Comment: I [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121547/143965) why Facebook employees don't answer Facebook questions despite their partnership with Stack Overflow so the CFO of Stack Overflow starts answering them.  ***Interesting.*** I've also asked [this same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103807/143965).

Comment: @OffBySome Yup. I wanted to see if the questions were as bad as your post made them out to be. Also, it's a conspiracy!

Comment: @MichaelPryor Is the conspiracy Stack Exchange trying to keep the dump truck loads of money from Facebook still dumping in? :) you have access to the key data that we don't, but the data we do have doesn't look good for Facebook questions any way you look at it.

Answer (score 6):

While I'm sure there's an intelligent reason why a non-Facebook tag needs to be added, forcing any would-be editor to add it is a terrible idea.

There are any number of reasons why someone might come across a question with poor grammar or spelling, and, with sufficient reputation, might want to correct it.  Forcing the editor to also add an appropriate tag presumes she has sufficient knowledge about the question's subject matter.

Let's not discourage passersby in the Facebook neighborhood from improving parts of the question, even if other parts—like tags—might for the moment remain no better.

Answer (score 0):

> when I go to try to make the question better by editing the title, changing grammar, etc, I'm forced to also give the question a new tag. What is the intent?

I think the intent is for you to make the question better :P.  Edits are supposed to be thorough; if the tags aren't useful for categorizing the question, they need to be fixed.  Same with titles — if a title is a duplicate of another, you'll have to change that too.

There's no nice way to enforce a rule change like this after the fact, and I think doing it on-edit is the best option.  Better than either yanking the question or allowing legacy junk indefinitely, IMO.

Comment: I think the friction created here was meant for the people asking the questions on fb.stackoverflow.com, not editors. If it was actually for editors to make the question better, this rule would apply whether my url bar said fb.stack/question/1234 or stack/question/1234

Comment: @MichaelPryor The question needs to be usefully categorized regardless of who's doing the categorization. I'd agree that the restriction should be applied regardless, though.