# Why does a question on facebook.stackoverflow require a non-facebook tag?

Tags: support, facebook.stackoverflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is a non-Facebook tag necessary?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118109/why-is-a-non-facebook-tag-necessary)

I just tried to submit a question to facebook.stackoverflow.com.

I forgot to tag it, so I got the error that it must have a facebook related tag.

I added a couple of relevant tags (opengraph, and facebook-opengraph).

Now submission fails with the error "Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because:

must include at least one tag not related to facebook".

Why should a question about facebook require one tag not related to facebook? Is there a bug here?

Comment: I'd like to get my question answered. To get the question submitted, I added the "java" tag, and it went through, even though the question has nothing to do with java (although my implementation is in java). Then I tried to go back and edit the post, and remove that tag, but the save is rejected for the same reason as above. There's clearly something wrong here, because it's a legitimate opengraph question (as per the suggested tags for facebook.stackoverflow.com), yet it shouldn't need a non-facebook related tag.

Comment: Totally agree with you and I'm sure most of the regular [facebook] users would agree as well. Unfortunately the reasoning is that one should take the time to find a tag that can work @_@ To which I call bull as I've been in this turmoil for months on end. I have made a feature request to kill this this pointless feature once and for all http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151444/remove-non-facebook-tag-requirement Place your vote to show your agreement or disagreement as I have used your question as an example